# Slow loading of RSS feeds into UITableView

Tags: iphone, rss, feed, tableview

I have a YouTube RSS feed set up to show YouTube videos in a tableview. When I load the controller though, it takes a long time to load the feed, so it appears for awhile that the app has frozen.

How can I load the view controller first, then show a loading/spinner while my app downloads the feed?

Comment: can i see the you example for this i have tried doing something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont load the feed on the main ui thread run it on background thread .

Take a look at ASINetworkQueue in asihttprequest  http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/